# How do character array work as as template argument?

Tags: templates, c++14

I have a bit of code that uses references to constexpr char arrays as template arguments. It turns out that new versions of MSVC [fails to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/MKRYEO).

But it has [no problems](https://godbolt.org/z/IOiyck) if I change the code to passing the array by value, which looks like this:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <char... Cs>
struct char_sequence {};

template <std::size_t N, const char (s)[N], typename T>
struct make_char_sequence_impl;

template <std::size_t N, const char (s)[N], std::size_t... i>
struct make_char_sequence_impl<N, s, std::index_sequence<i...>> {
  using type = char_sequence<s[i]...>;
};

template <std::size_t N, const char (Input)[N]>
using make_char_sequence =
    typename make_char_sequence_impl<N, Input,
                                     std::make_index_sequence<N - 1>>::type;

struct Delta {
  struct _alias_t {
    static constexpr const char _literal[] = "delta";
    using _name_t = make_char_sequence<sizeof(_literal), _literal>;
  };
};
```

According the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters):

> Array and function types may be written in a template declaration, but they are automatically replaced by pointer to object and pointer to function as appropriate.

But if the parameter `Input` is a pointer in `make_char_sequence`, then how can it be passed to `make_char_sequence_impl`, which is expecting an array of specific size? Is that legal C++?

Comment: Nothing expects an array of a specific size, since as you quoted every array parameter is implicitly replaced by a pointer parameter (which has no size information). Now if you were to have only `make_char_sequence_impl` take a `const char (&)[N]`, you'd see the error you expect with e.g. Clang.

Comment: @Quentin Oh dammit, struck by punctuation blindness again... Thanks for the explanation! So I can replace all the array stuff with pointers, which is much more readable anyway. Thanks again!